# error:unknown filesystem. Entering rescue mode... grub rescue

Tags: filesystem, grubrescue

Here's what's happening:

I think my laptop ran out of power and shut itself off (while the lid was closed).

When I started it back up I get:

```
error:unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

when I type in `ls` I get:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0) (fd1)
```

This doesn't work to fix it:

```
set root=(hd0,msdos5)
set prefix=(hd0,msdos5)/boot/grub    
insmod normal    
normal
```

Because whenever I type: `ls (hd0,msdos5)` or `ls (hd0,msdos1)` or `(hd0)` all I get is:

`Filesystem is unknown` or `Unknown filesystem`

Does this mean that my hard drive is broken?  Any advice?